# Coincidence detectors in Bell tests: How close is close enough?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement

When is a coincidence a coincidence? We know that to identify entangled photons, the electronics is set to look for simultaneous clicks at opposite detectors. The size of the window is to some degree arbitrary. What I am wondering is:

If you run a Bell-type entanglement experiment where you get, for example, 100 coincidences per second with a 100 picosecond interval, what happens if you double the window to 200 picoseconds? Do you expect, in general, to get 200 coincidences per second? I can think of three possible answers and I wonder which one is most true:

1. If your window is small enough, doubling the window doesn't matter because you are accurately identifying all available entangled particles. You still get 100 coincidences per second (or possible a few more for truly sporadic coincidence counts.)
2. Double the window, double the coincidences. You get 200 per second.
3. Double the window and you get four times the coincidences: 100 entirely in the first half of the window, 100 in the seconde half, and 200 "cross-coincidences". 400 per second in total.

I hope this question is meaningful and I wonder what the answer is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About $\pm 1$ nanosecond. The data can be visualized by plotting the difference between times of events at the two ends of the Bell experiment. The data from Gregor Weihs's experiment, Phys.Rev.Lett. 81, 5031 (1998), results in the attached graph (from an embedded postscript file, a much clearer PDF version is [here](http://pantheon.yale.edu/~pwm22/longdist34-Alice+-3ns.pdf)), which shows a very distinct drop off in coincidence outside a small range of time differences.[image: Time difference from each of 'Alice's events to the nearest 'Bob's event]

The graph shows the time difference from each of 'Alice's events to the nearest 'Bob's event, with only events within $\pm 3$ nanoseconds shown. In the ten second time-slot shown, that's 14841 of a total of 388660 Alice events. In a very few cases, there are more than one Bob events within 3 nanoseconds of the marked Alice event. As you see, increasing the width of the coincidence window above $\pm 1$ nanosecond will have relatively little impact on the numbers of coincidences. The different graphic symbols indicate Alice's experimental result for the particular Alice event without showing Bob's experimental result.

I regret that I don't have comparable data for a different experiment, so I can't tell you whether different experimental apparatuses show different dependencies on the coincidence window width.

EDIT: As a response to the comments below, a different graph, done long enough ago that I'm not sure that it's from the same data, but I'm pretty certain that the features are generic.[image: 8192 time differences] These graphs (the 2nd and 3rd graphs are just the first graph enlarged at the origin) plot the $i$'th *sorted* time difference between Alice's TOEs (Times Of Events) and the closest Bob's TOE for 8192 Alice events. The sorting of CTDs  (Closest TOE differences) makes the graph monotonely increasing. In this case, there are just 8192 Alice events instead of the 388660 Alice events in the full "*longdist34* " dataset. Looking at the second graph, there are just less than 400 Alice events for which the corresponding CTD is less than about 0.1 microseconds; in the 3rd graph, there are 135 events with CTDs less than 1 nanosecond (the jumps are because at that time I was working with CTDs with 1 nanosecond resolution, whereas I later discovered that there is more resolution in the data; the resolution and systematic variations of the two clocks' time stamps at the times of events (which are what are recorded in the Alice and Bob datasets) are definitely issues to understand, however I ignore them here).

In the first graph, one can see an almost linear rise from 350 events until, say, about 5000 events, then there are relatively fewer events that have longer time differences. The cutoff is inevitable, because Bob's events are rarely separated by long time intervals, so that the largest CTD is relatively unlikely to be longer than whatever the average time separation is between Bob's events. In this case, the longest CTD for 8192 Alice events is about 0.14 milliseconds. I think there's an answer in these graphs to your supplementary questions in your Comments below (albeit a graphical explanation, not what I'd call a mathematical explanation).

Comment: The data here isn't enough to characterize the quantum field (or, quantum optical) state that emerges from the PDC crystal. That would require various well-characterized complementary measurements of what is presumably some arbitrary superposition of multiple photon states. Adequate characterizations of such measurements requires a variety of well-characterized sources of multiple photon states. As Bjorn Wesen mentions, the laser that drives the PDC is not the only cause of events in the apparatus, but a separation into components such as thermal dark counts is a delicate theoretical choice.

Comment: A separation into *entangled* and *ordinary* photons is not strictly possible, insofar as any Alice event that *appears* not to have a corresponding Bob event has to be taken to be just a consequence of a failure to detect the corresponding event. In particular, the source emits only light of double the frequency of the detected light, so in the quantum modeling regime the nonlinear process implemented by the PDC crystal necessarily splits each source photon into two photons.

Comment: Point well taken. But you do see what I mean about two overlapping data sets, I hope? The density of events outside the 1-nanosecond band is just too steady to be the tail of a pure Poisson. If not ordinary photons, can I speculate that the entangled photons come in two varieties: singlet and triplet state? Perhaps the triplet state photons have narrower transition bandwidth so they are coherent over a longer time frame?

Comment: yes you should have a floor of non-coincidence counts both from dark counts of the detector itself (due to thermal excitation) and from photons arriving from something else than the laser and SPDC..

Comment: @bjorn well that's my problem. I'm trying to reconcile the total number of Alice events (388860 over 10 seconds) with the observed frequency of counts within the 3-nsec window. If I assume everything outside the 1 n-sec band is due to dark counts, then assuming Poisson there should be close to 4,000,000 Alice events over the 10-second interval. (By my ballpark estimate: I count about 200 events per second between the 1 nsec and 3 nsec band.) So I have a discrepancy of a factor of 10 in understanding the data as presented.

Comment: to clarify my problem: to ballpark the statistics, I take the reported 380,000 Alice events (approx. 40,000 per second) and find them to be spaced on average 25000 nseconds apart. Let's call them dark counts for sake of argument. Then I ask: how often will two adjacent dark counts occur 2.5 nseconds apart? You can see there is a factor of 10,000 here, which leads to an estimate of around 4 dark count coincidences per second. But from the graph I need to justify close to 200 coincidences outside the 1-nanosecond band. So what are they?

Comment: I don't see what reasons there are to assume that the distribution should be Poisson? I've uploaded the same graph, but with 100ns limits, to http://pantheon.yale.edu/~pwm22/longdist34-Alice+-100ns.pdf . You'll see that there's an echo effect in the data, between $\pm20$ns, that was not noticed when the experimental apparatus still existed, and which does not affect the violation of Bell-CHSH inequalities, but that otherwise the distribution of time differences between Alice events and the closest Bob event is more-or-less uniform. The echo effect is itself a deviation from Poisson.

Comment: Let's disregard the bizarre echo for now as an experimental artifact. I "assume" Poisson statistics because there is no need to explain Poisson behavior...it just "is". The clear deviation from Poisson, which your new data brings to light, means there is some unexplained physics going on. If we extrapolate: 15,000 events within the 3 nsec band, 20,000 events within the 100 nsec band...we get all 400,000 events within an 8000 nsec band, for an average spacing between events of 4 microsec. We should therefore "expect" around 2.5 million detection events...not the 400,000 reported. What gives?

Comment: Peter, your new data provides a tantalizing near-confirmation of my analysis of your earlier data. You have a zone 2-3 nsec wide of "entangled" events, and a second zone on the order of 100 times wider of "dark count" coincidences. Ignoring the entangled band, the "dark count" events are, on average about 10 msec apart. But you are missing the one piece of data that would tie it all together: the total elapsed time! 8000 events 10 msec apart should suggest a total elapsed time of 80 sec. This is the calculation which failed to line up in your ealier data set. Do you have the elapsed time?

Comment: This particular set of 8192 Alice events happened in 0.204805015 seconds (that's the difference between the first and last TOEs), very close to 25 microseconds per event average (I believe not significantly). This does come from a slightly different dataset from the other graphs, longdist35 in Gregor Weihs' data instead of longdist34, however these are quite closely comparable. Just less than 1/20th of the Alice events have a Bob event in coincidence.

Comment: OK, I mixed up micro and milliseconds, so my reading of the graph gives 10 microseconds average between events, within a factor of 2 give or take with what your revised data shows. This may be explainable by normal bunching (non-Poisson distribution of thermal etc. light). I still think the discrepancy (factor of six) in the first set of points is a little large, especially considering how much data you gave me to work with.

Answer (score -2):

Every coincidence test compares to the accidental chance rate. To find chance you use only one detector at a time to read the click rates, $R_1$ and $R_2$, for each detector. There is a time window, $\Delta t$, within which you will use to determine both the chance rate and the $\Delta t$ within which you will count as a coincidence in your experiment. The chance rate is $R_1 R_2 \Delta t$. When you run the experiment you use a time difference graph that should look like a peak in the middle of the graph, which is at zero click-time difference between the detectors. Here you will choose $\Delta t$ so that the bulk of that peak is used in your counting coincident clicks. Any peak in that graph means the experiment is reading better than chance. I have done many such experiments but they were with one "particle" emitted at a time instead of two that are used in a typical Bell test.